# connectionDidFinishLoading called twice with certain php scripts

Tags: php, objective-c

I have a well working class for http requests in form of a library which works great. But now recently I'm working on a project and the guys with the server side are not cooperating very well or are lazy to check.

I think the question is more for php, is it possible in any way to return something 2 times?

What happens is that for certain requests I receive in `connectionDidFinishLoading` an empty `array[]`, then I receive a second response with the correct output. For this reason my app crashes, i don't know exactly where because it's combined with some `cpp` to dispatch the event somewhere else. I fixed this by ignoring the `[]` response, but now it's getting ugly because sometimes a `[]` is a good response. I can fix this also but then is becoming a custom library rather than a library.

Comment: Can you show us some of your Objective-C code?

Comment: Yes, this is the one. I didn't updated the part which ignores the [] responses though. https://github.com/ralcr/sdk.ralcr/blob/master/NMEExtensions/sources/iphone/Https.mm

Answer (score -1):

Seems it was an error on my part after all, but not in the script i posted.